# PRAW 4: 400 ERROR when trying to download a users comments

Tags: python, python-2.7, praw

I'm trying to create a Reddit bot that when a username is mentioned it gets the users comments and sends it to an API to analyze them and return a request but when I try to download them it gives me

```
prawcore.exceptions.BadRequest: received 400 HTTP response
```

This is the code:

```
    if text.startswith('/u/PersonalityInsights'):
        print "Mentioned!"
        print comment
        username = text.split()[1]
        print username
        if username.startswith('/u/'):
            validusername = username[3:]
            print validusername
            global redditor
            redditor = bot.redditor(username)
        else:
            global redditor
            redditor = bot.redditor(username)
        file = codecs.open('userscommentsreddit.txt', 'w+', encoding='utf8')
        for comment in redditor.get_comments(limit=None):
            print comment.body
```

The method I'm using is: `get_comments(limit=None)`

in PRAW 3 it worked but here it fails. I tried lowercasing the username but it failed with the same error. The account I'm trying to download the comments is mine: /u/UnknownDeveloper

I tried lowering the username but the same error, Replaced the for loop with this: `for comment in redditor.comments.new(limit=None):` and still an error 400

If you are interested in the full code here is a link to a [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/TheRealUnknownDeveloper/124436b18ebe4bf2b842f92bb5282c83).

Version of Praw 4.1.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is almost a year old, and chances are you have moved on or solved this already, but I really like doing research and answering SO questions so here we go!:

Here is what the 400 error means, so we are on the same page:

> The HTTP 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server could not understand the request due to invalid syntax.<sup>[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400)</sup>

Now into the actual answer:

> The method I'm using is: get_comments(limit=None)
>
> in PRAW 3 it worked but here it fails. I tried lowercasing the username but it failed with the same error.

The `get_comments()` call was depreciated, and I assume you figured this out based on the fact you also tried the `comments.new()` function.

But that doesn't matter at all, because the real issue is in `redditor = bot.redditor(username)`. That call takes the raw username (without the `/u/`) So the solution to your code would be to remove the `/u/` from the username variable before calling `redditor = bot.redditor(username)`, or you could make things simpler by using regex to identify a valid username but only return the part after the /u/.